# Can I import a rectangle from one org-table into another org-table?

Tags: org-mode, org-table

I have an org document with two different-sized tables `table1` and `table2`.

```
#+TBLNAME: table1
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
|---+---+---+---+---+---+---|
|   |   | x | x | x | x | x |
|   |   | x | x | x | x | x |
|   |   | x | x | x | x | x |
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
#+TBLFM: @2$3..@4$7=x

#+TBLNAME: table2
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
|---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---|
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
|   |   |   |   | y | y | y | y | y |   |
|   |   |   |   | y | y | y | y | y |   |
|   |   |   |   | y | y | y | y | y |   |
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
#+TBLFM: @6$5..@8$9=y
```

The region in `table1` marked with `x`'s and the region in `table2` marked with `y`'s are both arrays with three rows and four columns. I want to import the information in the indicated region of `table2` into the indicated region of `table1`.

Reading through the org documentation it appears that something like

```
#+TBLFM: @2$3..@4$7='(identity remote(table2, <STUFF>))
```

might work, but I can't figure out what `<STUFF>` should be. Any ideas?

Comment: Technically, `<STUFF>` should be the range, i.e. `@6$5..@8$9`, but I'm afraid that importing rectangle won't work. At least I remember having problems specifying something more complex than a single value for all cell. But suppose you were to use Calc (rather than Lisp), the way I'd approach this is by trying `remote(table2, @6$5..@8$9)_(@#, $#)` i.e. Calc way of indexing a matrix.

Comment: So are you saying this is possible using calc? I'm having trouble seeing how.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go. The key was to recombine the rows back (for some reason when Org copies a rectangle area it flattens it).

```
#+TBLNAME: table1
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
|---+---+---+---+---+---+---|
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
|   |   | a | a | a | a | a |
|   |   | b | b | b | b | b |
|   |   | c | c | c | c | c |
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
#+TBLFM: @3$3..@5$7=arrange(remote(table2, @6$5..@8$9), 5)_(@# - 2)_($# - 2)

#+TBLNAME: table2
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
|---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---|
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
|   |   |   |   | a | a | a | a | a |   |
|   |   |   |   | b | b | b | b | b |   |
|   |   |   |   | c | c | c | c | c |   |
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
#+TBLFM: @6$5..@6$9=a::@7$5..@7$9=b::@8$5..@8$9=c
```

Answer (score 3):

To supplement [wvxvw](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/563/wvxvw)'s answer, you can also do this interactively by copying with `org-table-copy-region` and pasting with `org-paste-rectangle`.  I bind those two like this:

```el
;; table copy paste (C-c M-w is bound to `org-copy' by default)
(org-defkey org-mode-map (kbd "C-c M-w") 'org-table-copy-region)
(org-defkey org-mode-map (kbd "C-c M-y") 'org-table-paste-rectangle)
```